# add lists classes differently by looping

Tags: jquery

I have the following html...

```
<div id="banner">
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

And applied the following jquery:

```
$('#banner li:nth-child(1)').addClass('li1');
$('#banner li:nth-child(2)').addClass('li2');
$('#banner li:nth-child(3)').addClass('li3');
```

But I think this would be done easily as using for loop but can't get an idea on this. Could anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) variant that takes a function as argument

```
$('#banner li').addClass(function(idx){
    return 'li' + (idx + 1)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4VExj/)

Answer (score 1):

[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

[.addclass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

```
$('#banner li').each(function(i){
    $(this).addClass('li'+parseInt(++i));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/4VExj/4/)

Comment: it adds classes like `li01` not `li1`